# Embedding shared XML in Service Fabric Application Manifest

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We are using Service Fabric framework with `.net Core`. One of the things which started to become a bit problematic is some of our services / applications need the same parameters - which we're retyping for each of the application manifests.

Is there a way of sharing an XML snippet where you can reference in the application manifest / so the Service Fabric Applications which are using the same parameters can just reference that shared snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is not way to provide the parameters on separate files, but you could update the default `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` script to do so.

In you case you options are:

- Create separate files and create a script to merge it before deployment.
- Use a CI/CD process to do the configuration values and inject the values as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54446716/484222)
- Pass the shared values as JSON as a single parameter like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52860123/484222)
- Use a configuration server like Azure KeyVault and the applications load from there.

Is likely to doable in many other different ways, shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: This matches with my findings so far, thanks for confirming.